# How to get the length of longest string in an array

Tags: php, arrays

Say I have this array:

```
$array[] = 'foo';
$array[] = 'apple';
$array[] = '1234567890;
```

I want to get the length of the longest string in this array. In this case the longest string is `1234567890` and its length is 10.

Is this possible without looping through the array and checking each element?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

try

```
$maxlen = max(array_map('strlen', $ary));
```

Comment: @Tobia If you are saying that `"strlen"` is beautiful, you should look at JavaScript that passes `strlen` directly or Java that passes `::strlen` instead. Passing strings as callables is the source of a lot of language design problems in PHP.

Answer (score 4):

Sure:

```
function getmax($array, $cur, $curmax) {
  return $cur >= count($array) ? $curmax :
    getmax($array, $cur + 1, strlen($array[$cur]) > strlen($array[$curmax])
           ? $cur : $curmax);
}

$index_of_longest = getmax($my_array, 0, 0);
```

No loop there. ;-)

Comment: Disclaimer: I did understand that "no looping" in the question also implied "no recursion", but I could not resist...

Comment: Great answer :P
I would vote you up, had I not reached my vote limit for the day...

Answer (score 2):

A small addition to the ticket. I came here with a similar problem: Often you have to output just the longest string in an array.

For this, you can also use the top solution and extend it a little:

```
$lengths       = array_map('strlen', $ary);
$longestString = $ary[array_search(max($lengths), $lengths)];
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the arrays and use `strlen` to verify if the current length is longer than the previous.. and save the index of the longest string in a variable and use it later where you need that index.

Something like this..

```
$longest = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++)
{
  if($i > 0)
  {
    if(strlen($array[$i]) > strlen($array[$longest]))
    {
      $longest = $i;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: but the question clearly said "without looping through the array and checking each element?"

Comment: basic mechanics of doing such a task is still "looping", using array_map() for example just make it transparent to the user.

Comment: if you want to get a specified item from a set you will always have to loopthrough the set. In one way, or another. ;)

Answer (score 0):

This way you can find the shortest (or longest) element, but not its index.

```php
$shortest = array_reduce($array, function ($a, $b) {

    if ($a === null) {
        return $b;
    }

    return strlen($a) < strlen($b) ? $a : $b;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This's how to get the longest string "itself" from an array

```
$array = ['aa', 'b', 'c'];

$longest_str = array_reduce($array, fn ($carry, $item) => strlen($item) > strlen($carry) ? $item : $carry, "");

echo $longest_str; // aa
```