# checking array values are numbers

Tags: php

How can I check values in an array that has numbers containing only four digits? If there are strings or numbers longer than four digits, I want to echo an error message.

This is correct: `$searchText = '3423,  2453,  3245  ,  2425,  6765';`

This is wrong: `$searchText = '34d23,  244353,  fsddf  ,  2d4425,  674365';`

How can I do this?

I tried something like this...

```
$searchText = '3423,2453,3245,2425,6765';       


function validate($input) {
    $searchArray = array_map('trim', explode(',', $input));
    foreach($searchArray as $item) {
        if(filter_var($item, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) === false || strlen($item) != 4)
            return false;
    }
}

if(!validate($searchText))
    echo 'fail';
else
    echo 'pass';
```

output is: fail why is it?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 3):

```
$searchText = '3423, 2453, 3245 , 2425, 6765';

$vals = explode(",",$searchText);

foreach($vals as $v){
    $v = trim($v);
    if(is_numeric($v) && strlen($v)==4){
        echo 'good to go<br>';
    }elseif(is_numeric($v)){
        echo 'num but not 4 digits<br>';
    }else{
        echo 'string<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a way to check before going to explode?

Comment: unfortunately, since it's a string, there won't be a way of telling unless you break the string down.

Answer (score 2):

Those aren't arrays (they're strings), but you can handle the problem by splitting the string into an array and using [PHP's filtering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php) (`filter_var` in this case):

```php
if(!validate($searchText))
    // fail
else
    // pass

function validate($input)
{
    $inputArray = array_map('trim', explode(',', $input));
    foreach($inputArray as $item) {
        if(filter_var($item, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) === false || strlen($item) != 4)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't account for whitespace in the string, and delimiter is first param to explode, not second. Try `$searchArray = array_map('trim', explode(',', $searchText));` instead

Comment: check I updated code with your solution.. but its not working.

Comment: @TharangaNuwanKumara Sorry, my fault. I've edited my answer with `return true` at the end of the function.

Comment: @TharangaNuwanKumara What do you mean? It's only working on `$inputArray` inside that function. It doesn't actually edit your `$searchText` variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below logic.(If you mean "How can I check values in an array that has numbers containing only four digits? ", then below is the solution)

```
<?php
//you can use explode() function to convert your string into array.
//$searchText = '3423, 2453, 3245 , 2425, 6765';    
//$searchText = explode(",",$searchText);

$searchText = array('3423', '2453', '3245' , '2425', '6765');
$count = sizeof($searchText);
foreach($searchText as $key=>$value) {


    if (is_numeric($value) && preg_match('/^\d{4}$/', $value)) {

      // pass
    } else {

        $count--;
       // fail
    }

}

if($count == sizeof($searchText)) {
    echo "All good";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

replace your array variable with $ary this is return number of characters is in array

```
$maxlen = max(array_map('strlen', $ary));
```

for better explanation [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762191/how-to-get-the-length-of-longest-string-in-an-array)

Comment: yes replace it will return number of characters in the certain array