# Need to check longest prefix of a number

Tags: php

I've an array i.e. $arr(22, 123, 12345, 1234)
After user input a value i.e. 123456789 I need to check longest prefix exist in array or not. In above input case $arr[2] will be answer. If input is 123000 the answer will be $arr[1]. Input can be of any length.

Php hint will be appreciable

Comment: hint: `foreach` + `strpos`

Comment: Iterate over the array and check if each element appears at position 0 in the input. Remember the length and index of the longest element that is a prefix.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762191/how-to-get-the-length-of-longest-string-in-an-array

Comment: What he wants is: the user enters some number. Then find a number in the array which has as much as possible consecutive equal numbers at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for ($i = strlen($inputNumber); $i > 0; $i--)
    foreach ($numberArray as $number)
        if (strpos($number, substr($inputNumber, 0, $i)) === 0)
            $longestNumber = $number;
```

the result will be stored in $longestNumber (first check if there was a failure with `isset($longestNumber)`)

Comment: Thnx bwoebi it worked exactly as I want

Comment: @UsmanWali It's (nearly) every time somebody there who can decrypt such descriptions :P

Comment: mybad.. im not coding geek so I understand ur feelings :D